# Itanium cross-compiler for x86/64

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, cross-compiling, itanium

I need to compile my code for Itanium, but it seems that all of the compilers (ecc, gcc, orc) require an Itanium machine to do so. Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you going to test the executable?

Comment: Er, gcc can be a cross-compiler, what's the problem?

Comment: @Mark, I am, but on a simulator: IATO

Comment: Can't the simulator run the compiler ? However the cross compilation is probably better

Comment: No it can't, I need to compile it on my own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set gcc up as a cross compiler. This involves building binutils and gcc yourself.

The IA64wiki at http://www.gelato.unsw.edu.au/IA64wiki/CrossCompilation has a tutorial on how to set this up.

Comment: There used to be a script collection called `crosstool` that would take care of all the downloading and building of the myriad utilities and libraries for cross compilation...

Answer (score 1):

I can only tell how I did it, perhaps not the best way or best tools.

I developed a very small priority-based Itanium kernel and test tasks long time ago. I started to develop it again (demand paging, fork system call...). The last time I compiled it is a week ago.

What I found is that compiling a cross compiler is a very hard task nowadays for IA64. And to get gcc and binutils to work together is an other problem.
I tried many times compile cross compiler and binutils - no success).
It seems that Itanium support has been forgotten, at least very much worse than some years again.

However, I found packages for the cross compiler, binutils and ski simulator binary. All starts working immediately (well, ski does not show TLB info).

I have Ubuntu 12, Linux kernel 3.2 AMD64

How to find the tools:

- Ski:

  - Ubuntu Sotfware Center: Ski/IA-64 instruction set simulator (binary)
- Cross tools (work together!):

  - gcc-ia64-linux-gnu-4.7.1-0.1.20120606.fc18.1.x86_64.rpm
  - binutils-ia64-linux-gnu-2.22.52.0.3-3.fc18.x86_64.rpm

My web page: http://www.isosika.net/

(Hmm...  I compiled the Kernel, I think that application library support can be bad or non existent?)

Comment: there is lots of application support, see the debian ia64 port: https://www.debian.org/ports/ia64/

Answer (score 0):

There's Itanium version of Windows, so of course Visual studio can generate code for Itanium

Comment: it's no longer true. Visual dropped support for Itanium.

Comment: I didn't mention any version. Neither did the OP. That means at least one version of MSVC supported Itanium

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 is the last version to support Itanium according to http://www.infoq.com/news/2010/04/Itanium-Dropped

Comment: @JanusTroelsen are you assuming that the OP is using VS 2012 or newer?